# Iron Golem Farm not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built an Iron Golem Farm in the sky above my spawn chunk, ive shoved 10 villagers there and i have 64 doors. I have been waiting for 3 hours but not even 1 golem has spawned. I know it takes some time for the minecraft engine to recognize the village but after 3 hours i think something is wrong.

Here are the screenshots so you can get an idea what its like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
what might be the problem here ?

Comment: I think you need a solid floor on the outside in front of the doors, but I'm not too sure. But that's something you could try.

Comment: I did a lot of research on the whole "village" enigma and everywhere it was stated that a door with a solid block on top is considered a house, even if its only one block. Good suggestion btw I was doubting that was the problem at first too...

Comment: Doors need more ground without full sunlight on one side of them. Did adding ground work for you?

Comment: Yes I did add them, but these is something else that bothers me, there is a block behind the door [ive updated the question to show the screenshot] which might be causing the doors to not be considered a village?

Comment: I tried trading with the villagers in order to get some idea as to are the doors even recognized and the answer is NO...after 3 trades the villagers did not want to breed. This means our doors arent considered houses... The question is what is wrong....

Comment: Is this something you can upload?  Or a structure of it?  I have built many iron farms, some very similar to yours.  I would have thought yours would work just looking at the images.  If you watch [this video on Nims design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dev3Ls8papM), you will see the doors are setup almost exactly the same and this design does work on 1.12.2.  You might feed the villagers to see if they become willing.

Comment: Try the ground that I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The farm started working after about 8 hours of idle state... the game engine seems to take some time to recognize villages once in a while... thanks for the good ideas from everyone though!